# Problem in storing values in array in one loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I want to store value 0.2 in my 778 arrays. but the result shows "none" as the values.

What I want to do:
[0.2,0.2,0.2] for 778

[None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None....]

```
weight=[]
i=0
while i <=777:
    value=0.2
    weight[i]= weight.append(value)
    i=i+1
weight
```

expected results:
[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]~~~~ until 778 iteration

Comment: `append` appends in-place; doesn't return anything. Hence, `None`.

Answer (score 3):

Just do `weight.append(value)`.

With `weight[i]= weight.append(value)`, you set `weight[i]` to the return value of `append`. `append` modifies the list in place, and doesn't have any useful value to return, so it returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is here 
`weight[i]= weight.append(value)`
. It should be `weight.append(value)`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using this way.

```
 >>> [.2 for i in range(10)]
 [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
```